# Using graphics card in VM environment

Tags: graphics-card, vmware

I need to utilize a graphics card when working on a VMWare VM. I googled this but the articles were too technical for me. Can someone plainly explain what is the configuration for doing this.

Can the card be connected to the workstation or should it be connected to the server? It would be more simple for me if workstation.

I understand the server is a blade center with Xeon processors.

Comment: I think that if you follow the guide you'll be ok https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln288103/how-to-enable-a-vmware-virtual-machine-for-gpu-pass-through?lang=en

Comment: Are you using Workstation Pro 14? You need ESX for GPU pass-through.